# How to open javascript popup with text box

Tags: javascript

I have task in my project which is open popup into javascript in html there is only hyper link whenever click on link then open popup and inside textbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="somnath.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" id="somnath"> Click Here Me</a>

    </body>
    </htm
```

Comment: nothing can be understood from this code

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase your problem-statement.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for this

```js
function pop() {
    prompt("Enter something!", "Text");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pop()">Click</button>
```

**Updated**

Check this

```js
function pop() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.popup {
    display: inline-block;
}
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 20px;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    right:150px;
}
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="#" onclick="pop()">Click</a>
  <div class="popup">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
      Enter your name: <input type="text" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it is possible without prompt not button use  hyperlink

Comment: can anyone help me for doing popup into javascript

Comment: @sms check my updated answer.

Comment: this is correct answer but  html  code should be in somnath.js javascript not into html page

Comment: @sms buddy i think you're a absolute beginner, create a file with the name **somnath.js** and add the script code into it and link the file with this tag in your html `<script src="somnath.js"></script>`

Comment: @hitehs thanks for quick reply everything is correct but my requirement is without prompt create popup

Comment: `popup without prompt ` meaning ? U want to make a modal to take user input ?

Comment: is it possible modal in javascript

Comment: yup its possible...adding an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML file should be like this,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="somnath.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And there should be one js file with name somnath.js and content,

```
function myFunction() {
    prompt("You can enter your text below", "Text");
}
```

Comment: i don't want to use prompt default function  use only hyperlink into html not button

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small modal in javascript. This requires jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#emailModal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Enter your information",
    buttons: {
        "Send": function() {
            $('#emailPost2').submit();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

// Show the modal form when clicked.
$('#emailJQButton').click(function() {
    $("#emailModal").dialog('open');
});

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rGwnQ/1/)